# boost::serialization formatting

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have to use class Matrix4x4 from some 3rd party library, and I need to serialize it.

**1.** Is it ok to create header(3rdparty_serialization.h) that will contain all serialization that is needed for 3rd party libraries, like Matrix4x4:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, Matrix4x4 & m, const unsigned int version)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4;++i)
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 4;++j)
        {
            auto& e = m[i][j];
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e);
        }
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

**2.** Is this definition of function "serialize" for Matrix4x4 correct?

**3.** How to customize formatting of Matrix4x4 serialization? 
Now, I have output:

```
<m class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <e>1</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>1</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>1</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>0</e>
    <e>1</e>
</m>
```

I want something like this:

```
<m class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <e>1;0;0;0</e>
        <e>0;1;0;0</e>
        <e>0;0;1;0</e>
        <e>0;0;0;1</e>
</m>
```

or other more compact and readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Yes.

**2.** Yes, assuming `Matrix` is not within a namespace.

**3.** You could try serializing `std::string`s instead of individual elements.  However, this is a bit wasteful since you will need to format and parse the strings.  Also not optimal for size if you want to use e.g. `binary_[io]archive`.

Comment: I believe there should be some kind of attributes, etc.

Comment: Boost serialization is mostly archive type agnostic.  Attributes are something for XML only yet there are also standard text and binary archives, not to mention you could in principle write your own too.  You already have to create those name-value pairs, of which the name part is not used in text or binary.  Adding even more complexity for XML sake was probably considered too much.

Comment: I don't think that attributes can affect type of archive. For binary archive we can skip these attributes easily.

Answer (score 3):

There a couple of ways to do this. The easiest way  would be to make a special verision of serialize for xml_archive.  This would keep the change from infecting other archive types.  Try something like:

```
template<>
void save(boost::archive::xml_archive & ar, const Matrix4x4 & m, const unsigned int version)
{
    std::string e;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4;++i){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 4;++j)
        {
            e +=  std::string(m[i][j]);
            e += ';';
        }
    }
    ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e)
}

// similar for load
```

Robert Ramey